PACE – GENERIC MAPPING implementation in java for android
I am currently working on a project where I need to translate a C# method to code compatible with Android . Unfortunately, I am facing some difficulties and would like to know if anyone is familiar with android and apdu and cryptography
Here is the method in question in c#:
public PaceKeys initiatePaceGenMapping()
{
    this.sendSelectApplet();
    PaceKeys paceKeys = new PaceKeys();
    // Paramètres du domaine pour la courbe ECC-NIST 256
    X9ECParameters curve = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1");
    // Utilisation des paramètres déjà connus
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger prime = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger a = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC", 16);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger order = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBCE6FAADA7179E84F3B9CAC2FC632551", 16);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger b = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("5AC635D8AA3A93E7B3EBBD55769886BC651D06B0CC53B0F63BCE3C3E27D2604B", 16);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger G_X = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("6B17D1F2E12C4247F8BCE6E563A440F277037D812DEB33A0F4A13945D898C296", 16);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger G_Y = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger("4FE342E2FE1A7F9B8EE7EB4A7C0F9E162BCE33576B315ECECBB6406837BF51F5", 16);
    Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint basePoint = curve.Curve.CreatePoint(G_X, G_Y);

    ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, basePoint, order, curve.H, curve.GetSeed());

    //  •   Read EF.DIR and EF.CardAccess (applet capabilities)
    string selectEF_F000 = executeCommandeSec("00A40000023F00");
    if (string.Equals(selectEF_F000, "9000"))
    {
        string selectEF_CardAccess = executeCommandeSec("00a4020c02011c");
        if (string.Equals(selectEF_CardAccess, "9000"))
        {
            string readBinaryCardAccess1 = executeCommandeSec("00b0000005");
            string readBinaryCardAccess2 = executeCommandeSec("00b000055b");

//  •   Select algorithm (INS 22)
string setMSE = executeCommandeSec("0022c1a412800a04007f0007020204020283010384010c");
if (string.Equals(setMSE, "9000"))
{
//  •   The host requests PACE for authentication, possibly giving a preference : 
 string paceAuthenticationREQUEST = executeCommandeSec("10860000027c0000");
//  •   The card responds with a 128-bit (16 byte) random number (nonce) encrypted with PACE_nonce_AES128key  : 7C 12 80 10 <encrypted_nonce>
int startIndex = paceAuthenticationREQUEST.IndexOf("7C128010") + "7C128010".Length;
   // Trouver l'index de fin de la sous-chaîne
  int endIndex = paceAuthenticationREQUEST.IndexOf("9000", startIndex);

 // Extraire la sous-chaîne : representant Key: z - encrypted nonce (z [PACE])
  string encryptedNonce = paceAuthenticationREQUEST.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);

 //  the host decrypts the 128-bit nonce with PACE_nonce_AES128key derived from user input as described above
                byte[] bytesEncryptedNonce = StringUtils.ToByteArray(encryptedNonce);

  // Key: K - derived key from shared secret : trouver la clé dérivée du PIN
  string derivedKeySH = calculerSHA1("3132333400000003");
byte[] bytesDerivedKeySH = StringUtils.ToByteArray(derivedKeySH);

//  •   [decrypt nonce nonce]
byte[] bytesDecryptedNonce = decryptAES(bytesEncryptedNonce, bytesDerivedKeySH);
string decryptedNonce = byteToHexStr(bytesDecryptedNonce);
  Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger nonce = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(decryptedNonce, 16);

 //  •  [generate random number as private key SKPCD for DHKA]           
  SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

  int randomNumber = random.NextInt();
Console.WriteLine("Nombre aléatoire : " + randomNumber);

Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger SKPCD = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(domainParams.Curve.Order.BitLength, random).Mod(domainParams.Curve.Order);
Console.WriteLine("Secrete Key SKPCD : " + SKPCD);
 // •   [calculate ephermeral PKPCD = BasePoint G * SKPCD]
 Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint PKPCD = domainParams.G.Multiply(SKPCD).Normalize();
 Console.WriteLine("Public Key PKPCD du terminal: " + PKPCD);
// Convertir les coordonnées X et Y en hexadécimal
 /* string PKPCDXHex = PKPCD.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToString(16);
 string PKPCDYHex = PKPCD.YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToString(16);*/

 // Convertir les coordonnées X et Y en hexadécimal
  byte[] PKPCDXBytes = PKPCD.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned();
   byte[] PKPCDYBytes = PKPCD.YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned();
 string PKPCDXHex = BitConverter.ToString(PKPCDXBytes).Replace("-", "");
  string PKPCDYHex = BitConverter.ToString(PKPCDYBytes).Replace("-", "");

//  •   Send PKPCD and Receive PKPICC from card
 string requestPKicc = "10860000457C43814104" + PKPCDXHex + PKPCDYHex + "00";
string reponsePKicc = executeCommandeSec(requestPKicc);

 // Définir les positions de début et de fin de la sous-chaîne
int entete = 10; // Après les 4 premiers octets
 int sw = reponsePKicc.Length - 4; // Avant les 4 derniers octets

  // Extraire la sous-chaîne
  reponsePKicc = reponsePKicc.Substring(entete, sw - entete);

 string PKICCXHex = reponsePKicc.Substring(0, reponsePKicc.Length / 2);
  string PKICCYHex = reponsePKicc.Substring(reponsePKicc.Length / 2);

 Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint PKPICC = curve.Curve.CreatePoint(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(PKICCXHex, 16), new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(PKICCYHex, 16));
                Console.WriteLine("Public Key PKICC de la carte: " + PKPICC);
                //  •   [build shared secret: H = PKPICC * SKPCD = G * SKPICC * SKPCD]
                Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint H = PKPICC.Multiply(SKPCD).Normalize();
                Console.WriteLine("Secret Partagé H : " + H);
                //  •   [build new base point:] :  Gmap = G * s + H = G * s + G * SKPICC * SKPCD = G * (s + SKPICC * SKPCD)
                Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint Gmap = basePoint.Multiply(nonce); Gmap = Gmap.Add(H).Normalize();
                Console.WriteLine("Nouveau Point de base Gmap : " + Gmap);
                //  •   [generate random number as private key SKPCD,map for DHKA]            
                Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger SKPCDMap = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Gmap.Curve.Order.BitLength, random).Mod(Gmap.Curve.Order);
                Console.WriteLine("Nouvel clé secrete SKPCDMap : " + SKPCDMap);

                //  •   [calculate ephermeral PKPCD,map = BasePoint Gmap * SKPCD,map]
                Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint PKPCDMap = Gmap.Multiply(SKPCDMap).Normalize();
                Console.WriteLine("Nouvelle clé publique éphémère  PKPCDMap du terminal : " + PKPCDMap);

                // Convertir les coordonnées X et Y en hexadécimal
                string PKPCDMapXHex = PKPCDMap.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToString(16);
                string PKPCDMapYHex = PKPCDMap.YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToString(16);

                //  •   Send PKPCD,map and Receive PKPICC,map from card
                string requestPKpcdmap = "10860000457c43834104" + PKPCDMapXHex + PKPCDMapYHex + "00";
                string responsePKpcdmap = executeCommandeSec(requestPKpcdmap);                       
                sw = responsePKpcdmap.Length - 4;

 
  // Extraire la sous-chaîne
  if (responsePKpcdmap.Length > 4)
  {
 responsePKpcdmap = responsePKpcdmap.Substring(entete, sw - entete);

string PKICCMapXHex = responsePKpcdmap.Substring(0, responsePKpcdmap.Length / 2);
string PKICCMapYHex = responsePKpcdmap.Substring(responsePKpcdmap.Length / 2);

Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint PKPICCMap = curve.Curve.CreatePoint(new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(PKICCMapXHex, 16), new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(PKICCMapYHex, 16));
 Console.WriteLine("Nouvelle clé publique éphémère  de la puce PKPICCMap : " + PKPICCMap);
 // •   [build Hmap = PKPICC,map * SKPCD,map = Gmap * SKPICC,map * SKPCD,map]
Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint Hmap = PKPICCMap.Multiply(SKPCDMap).Normalize();
byte[] HmapBytes = StringUtils.ToByteArray(Hmap.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToString(16));

// •    Derive session keys Kenc and Kmac  from Hmap
  string Kenc = calculerSHA1(Hmap.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToString(16) + "00000001");
  string Kmac = calculerSHA1(Hmap.XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToString(16) + "00000002");
  Console.WriteLine("Clé encryption Kenc : " + Kenc);
  Console.WriteLine("Clé mac Kmac : " + Kmac);
  // •  Calculate token: TPICC = MAC(Kmac , PKPCD,map), TPCD = MAC(Kmac, PKPICC,map)

string PKICCMap = "04" + PKICCMapXHex + PKICCMapYHex;
string auth_token_host = calculateCMAC(Kmac, PKICCMap);
Console.WriteLine("Token d'authentification : " + auth_token_host);
string tpicc = executeCommandeSec("008600000c7c0a8508" + auth_token_host);
                    Console.WriteLine("Réponse tpicc : " + tpicc);
                    if (tpicc != null && tpicc.Length > 4)
                    {
                        sw = tpicc.Length - 4;
                        string auth_token_tpicc = tpicc.Substring(8, sw - 8);

                        paceKeys.keyMac = Kmac;
                        paceKeys.keyEnc = Kenc;
                        Console.WriteLine("Pace object : keyMac et keyEnc " + paceKeys.keyMac + " " + paceKeys.keyEnc);
                        if (paceKeys.keyMac != null || paceKeys.keyEnc != null)
                        {
                            sm = new SecureMessaging(StringUtils.ToByteArray(Kmac), StringUtils.ToByteArray(Kenc));
                            return paceKeys;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String VerifyPUK = executeCommande("00200089083132333435363738");
                            Console.WriteLine("Verify PUK :  " +VerifyPUK);
                            this.sendSelectApplet();
                            this.initiatePaceGenMapping();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String VerifyPUK = executeCommande("00200089083132333435363738");
                        Console.WriteLine("Verify PUK :  " + VerifyPUK);
                        this.sendSelectApplet();
                        this.initiatePaceGenMapping();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    String VerifyPUK = executeCommande("00200089083132333435363738");
                    Console.WriteLine("Verify PUK :  " + VerifyPUK);
                    this.sendSelectApplet();
                    this.initiatePaceGenMapping();
                }

            }

        }
    }
    return paceKeys;

}


This method works correctly on C#, it consists of exchanging keys between a terminal and a smart card.
I can read secure smart cards with PACE GENERIC MAPPING.
Here is my android code i'm but i'm having an error when i have to send
command authentication with the auth_token at the end :
// Further processing with the result
 return executeCommandeSecAsync("008600000c7c0a8508" + result);   

I'm having an 63Cx error apdu that mean the finded result is not good.
The android code here :
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
   public CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<PaceKeys>> initiatePaceGenMapping() {
       return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           try {
               this.sendSelectApplet();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }

           PaceKeys paceKeys = new PaceKeys();
           // Parameters for ECC-NIST P-256 curve
           X9ECParameters curve = SECNamedCurves.getByName("secp256r1");
           // Use known parameters
           BigInteger prime = new BigInteger("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", 16);
           BigInteger a = new BigInteger("FFFFFFFF00000001000000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC", 16);
           BigInteger order = new BigInteger("FFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFBCE6FAADA7179E84F3B9CAC2FC632551", 16);
           BigInteger b = new BigInteger("5AC635D8AA3A93E7B3EBBD55769886BC651D06B0CC53B0F63BCE3C3E27D2604B", 16);
           BigInteger G_X = new BigInteger("6B17D1F2E12C4247F8BCE6E563A440F277037D812DEB33A0F4A13945D898C296", 16);
           BigInteger G_Y = new BigInteger("4FE342E2FE1A7F9B8EE7EB4A7C0F9E162BCE33576B315ECECBB6406837BF51F5", 16);
           ECPoint basePoint = curve.getCurve().createPoint(G_X, G_Y);

           ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curve.getCurve(), basePoint, order, curve.getH(), curve.getSeed());
           SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
           byte[] randomBytes = new byte[16];
           random.nextBytes(randomBytes);
           int randomNumber = random.nextInt();
           Log.d("Nombre aléatoire : ", String.valueOf(randomNumber));
           final BigInteger[] SKPCD = new BigInteger[1];
           final BigInteger[] nonce = new BigInteger[1];
           return executeCommandeSecAsync("00A40000023F00")
                   .thenCompose(selectEF_F000 -> {
                       if ("9000".equals(selectEF_F000)) {
                           return executeCommandeSecAsync("00a4020c02011c")
                                   .thenCompose(selectEF_CardAccess -> {
                                       if ("9000".equals(selectEF_CardAccess)) {
                                           return executeCommandeSecAsync("00b0000005")
                                                   .thenCompose(read_binary_1 -> executeCommandeSecAsync("00b000055b"))
                                                   .thenCompose(read_binary_2 -> executeCommandeSecAsync("0022c1a412800a04007f0007020204020283010384010c"));
                                       }
                                       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                                   });
                       }
                       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                   })
                   .thenCompose(setMSE -> {
                           return executeCommandeSecAsync("10860000027c0000")
                                   .thenCompose(paceAuthenticationREQUEST -> {
                                       int startIndex = paceAuthenticationREQUEST.indexOf("7C128010") + "7C128010".length();
                                       int endIndex = paceAuthenticationREQUEST.indexOf("9000", startIndex);
                                       String encryptedNonce = paceAuthenticationREQUEST.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

                                       byte[] bytesEncryptedNonce = StringUtils.toByteArray(encryptedNonce);

                                       String derivedKeySH = calculerSHA1("3132333400000003");
                                       byte[] bytesDerivedKeySH = StringUtils.toByteArray(derivedKeySH);

                                       byte[] bytesDecryptedNonce = decryptAES(bytesEncryptedNonce, bytesDerivedKeySH);
                                       String decryptedNonce = bytesToHex(bytesDecryptedNonce);
                                       nonce[0] = new BigInteger(decryptedNonce, 16);
                                       Log.d("Order Length", String.valueOf(order.bitLength()));
                                       SKPCD[0] = (new BigInteger(order.bitLength(), random)).mod(order);
                                       //SKPCD[0] = new BigInteger(domainParams.getCurve().getOrder().bitLength(), random).mod(domainParams.getCurve().getOrder());
                                       Log.d("Secrete Key SKPCD : ", String.valueOf(SKPCD[0]));

                                       ECPoint PKPCD = domainParams.getG().multiply(SKPCD[0]).normalize();
                                       Log.d("Public Key PKPCD du terminal: ", PKPCD.toString());
                                       String pkpcdX = String.format("%064x", PKPCD.getXCoord().toBigInteger());
                                       String pkpcdY = String.format("%064x", PKPCD.getYCoord().toBigInteger());

                                       Log.d("PKPCD X", pkpcdX);
                                       Log.d("PKPCD Y", pkpcdY);

                                       String requestPKicc = "10860000457C43814104" + pkpcdX + pkpcdY + "00";
                                       Log.d("requestPKicc", requestPKicc);
                                       //Log.d("PKPCD X", PKPCD.getXCoord().toBigInteger().toString(16));
                                       //Log.d("PKPCD Y", PKPCD.getYCoord().toBigInteger().toString(16));

                                       //String requestPKicc = "10860000457C43814104" + PKPCD.getXCoord().toBigInteger().toString(16) + PKPCD.getYCoord().toBigInteger().toString(16) + "00";
                                       return executeCommandeSecAsync(requestPKicc);
                                   });

                      // return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                   })
                   .thenCompose(reponsePKicc -> {
                       if (reponsePKicc != null) {
                           int entete = 10;
                           AtomicInteger sw = new AtomicInteger(reponsePKicc.length() - 4);

                           reponsePKicc = reponsePKicc.substring(entete, sw.get());

                           String PKICCXHex = reponsePKicc.substring(0, reponsePKicc.length() / 2);
                           String PKICCYHex = reponsePKicc.substring(reponsePKicc.length() / 2);
                           out.println("PKICCXHex");
                           out.println(PKICCXHex);
                           out.println("PKICCYHex");
                           out.println(PKICCYHex);

                           ECPoint PKPICC = curve.getCurve().createPoint(new BigInteger(PKICCXHex, 16), new BigInteger(PKICCYHex, 16));
                           Log.d("Public Key PKICC de la carte: ",PKPICC.toString());

                           ECPoint H = PKPICC.multiply(SKPCD[0]).normalize();
                           Log.d("Secret Partagé H : ", H.toString());

                           ECPoint Gmap = basePoint.multiply(nonce[0]);
                           Gmap = Gmap.add(H).normalize();
                           Log.d("Nouveau Point de base Gmap : ",Gmap.toString());
                            BigInteger SKPCDMap = new BigInteger(order.bitLength(), random).mod(order);
                           Log.d("Nouvel clé secrete SKPCDMap ",SKPCDMap.toString());

                           ECPoint PKPCDMap = Gmap.multiply(SKPCDMap).normalize();
                           Log.d("Nouvelle clé publique éphémère  PKPCDMap du terminal : ",PKPCDMap.toString());
                           String.format("%064x", PKPCDMap.getXCoord().toBigInteger());
                           String PKPCDMapXHex = String.format("%064x", PKPCDMap.getXCoord().toBigInteger());
                           String PKPCDMapYHex = String.format("%064x", PKPCDMap.getYCoord().toBigInteger());
                           out.println("PKPCDMapXHex");
                           out.println(PKPCDMapXHex);
                           out.println("PKPCDMapYHex");
                           out.println(PKPCDMapYHex);

                           String requestPKpcdmap = "10860000457c43834104" + PKPCDMapXHex + PKPCDMapYHex + "00";
                           return executeCommandeSecAsync(requestPKpcdmap)
                                   .thenCompose(responsePKpcdmap -> {
                                       out.println("responsePKpcdmap");
                                       out.println(responsePKpcdmap);
                                       sw.set(responsePKpcdmap.length() - 4);
       if (responsePKpcdmap.length() > 4) {
     responsePKpcdmap = responsePKpcdmap.substring(entete, sw.get());

                                           String PKICCMapXHex = responsePKpcdmap.substring(0, responsePKpcdmap.length() / 2);
                                           //PKICCMapXHex = String.format("%064s", PKICCMapXHex).replace(' ', '0');
                                           out.println("PKICCMapXHex");
                                           out.println(PKICCMapXHex);                                            String PKICCMapYHex = responsePKpcdmap.substring(responsePKpcdmap.length() / 2);
                                           //PKICCMapYHex = String.format("%064s", PKICCMapYHex).replace(' ', '0');
                                           out.println("PKICCMapYHex");
                                           out.println(PKICCMapYHex);                                            ECPoint PKPICCMap = curve.getCurve().createPoint(new BigInteger(PKICCMapXHex, 16), new BigInteger(PKICCMapYHex, 16));
                                           Log.d("Nouvelle clé publique éphémère  de la puce PKPICCMap : ",PKPICCMap.toString());
                                           ECPoint Hmap = PKPICCMap.multiply(SKPCDMap).normalize();
                                           byte[] HmapBytes = APDUScript.toBytes(Hmap.getXCoord().toBigInteger().toString(16));

String Kenc = calculerSHA1(Hmap.getXCoord().toBigInteger().toString(16) + "00000001");
                                           String Kmac = calculerSHA1(Hmap.getXCoord().toBigInteger().toString(16) + "00000002");
                                           Log.d("Clé encryption Kenc : ",Kenc);
                                           Log.d("Clé mac Kmac : ",Kmac);
                                           String PKICCMap = "04" + PKICCMapXHex + PKICCMapYHex;
return calculateCMACAsync(Kmac, PKICCMap)
      .thenCompose(result -> {
                                                       Log.d("Token d'authentification : ",result);
                                                       out.println("Async CMAC result: " + result);
                                                       // Further processing with the result
                                                       return executeCommandeSecAsync("008600000c7c0a8508" + result)
                                                               .thenCompose(tpicc -> {
                                                                   Log.d("Réponse tpicc : ",tpicc);
                                                                   out.println("tpicc");
                                                                   out.println(tpicc);
                                                                   if (tpicc != null && tpicc.length() > 4) {
                                                                       sw.set(tpicc.length() - 4);
                                                                       String auth_token_tpicc = tpicc.substring(8, sw.get() - 8);
                                                                       paceKeys.setKeyMac(Kmac);
                                                                       paceKeys.setKeyEnc(Kenc);
  sm = new SecureMessaging(APDUScript.toBytes(Kmac), APDUScript.toBytes(Kenc));
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(paceKeys);
} else {
     return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                                                                           try {
                                                                               this.sendSelectApplet();
                                                                               return this.initiatePaceGenMapping().join();
                                                                           } catch (IOException e)             throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
 });
                                                                   }      });
      })
.exceptionally(ex -> {
                                                       out.println("Error calculating CMAC: " + ex.getMessage());
   throw new RuntimeException(ex);
   });
    } else {
                                           return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
                                                   this.sendSelectApplet();
                                                   return this.initiatePaceGenMapping().join();
   } catch (IOException e) {     throw new RuntimeException(e);
     }
         });   }
});
 }
                       return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
                   })
                   .exceptionally(ex -> {
                       out.println("Error during PACE initialization: " + ex.getMessage());
                       throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                   })
                   .thenApply(v -> paceKeys);
       });
   }

The logs of java android :
Nombre aléatoire : -1847558116

Secrete Key SKPC : 99411499502711625067430159080481548425536475748688452040238473829264151654625

Public Key du terminal:(4ce7204130e3f76f17e5ae774e9c009cafb3c400efcf550e730694801b000,6e03acf31e71b3f7ef2504b4a0e8f7fbcb4a7412a73a90b7f671c46502c1,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)

Public Key... la carte:(37b27601450ba362e38a06e5a0bc3908a9acbf9f8928a0f8176ff677a0ec707e,22eee537e51b8e699626c506a6771c527bc5c4c2e12fc5390b12f969ce,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
 
Secret Partagé H :  (3b221aeb876b2abac34ff80a63a5215ba69a134b8e03c71f1369542ccf926940,63a1a906c4c1e7bb093c21e20f7f428e57a6f7533cc89176f4cf7941,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
 
Nouveau Point e ...ase Gmap :(f44b4690e6c385048180f0118048624333b915395e9b5903ca2028c2e2a7,2c4cb8426c801e1f004ab8ea1648a658bab315ca0c1c51abf45f20b6c3,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
 
Nouvel clé secrete SKPCMap 76590852103704156605428334633305874342709637479155542757479728567671409871647
 
Nouvelle c...terminal :(73eb533e3e635c15a949b9c882bc1177a850eaef3b4647c513a0effcbaf,67b4ffcf6442a594b2279eb8a59704a4771f1b4b9b231e568a9466ee5c5e,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)

Nouvelle c...KPICCMap :(8a38b72b61e73ae6ee975e87aa130f0072c087f7884bc597e3a6e3f805f00,67a20874760ffb87c3c6e9a5f2a91a3bb24930814657accab32cb493e87,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)

Clé encryption Kenc :  95aa6cf8cc62be22f51eef925ae559b
 
Clé mac Kmac :665f62a79e05bf6e6019279a61ec6
 
Token 'au...fication :4E609F36F2134355

Réponse tpicc :  63CE

And the log of c# part :
Nombre aléatoire : 546022152
Secrete Key SKPCD : 39056701917978664281168567963160392468908985681161446064353125940764560648281
Public Key PKPCD du terminal: (ce5e8881f7d4bd34a040ceb28d9861aeb39a344ce8400680f10e8431b99f8867,92921424adae9f5eec584acb454e7438aedb6fb444d484db5d7fa31057d281fe,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
10860000457C43814104CE5E8881F7D4BD34A040CEB28D9861AEB39A344CE8400680F10E8431B99F886792921424ADAE9F5EEC584ACB454E7438AEDB6FB444D484DB5D7FA31057D281FE00
Send=>10860000457C43814104CE5E8881F7D4BD34A040CEB28D9861AEB39A344CE8400680F10E8431B99F886792921424ADAE9F5EEC584ACB454E7438AEDB6FB444D484DB5D7FA31057D281FE00
Get<=7C438241047D7D6E0B0911D3C46ACD04FD2215B81FCCF680C4C0D292D73BC14831462E05FA4C34D4B103D4204904869C7E65FD486E140D8E0F4AF299C6D92BDCBAC63822729000

Public Key PKICC de la carte: (7d7d6e0b0911d3c46acd04fd2215b81fccf680c4c0d292d73bc14831462e05fa,4c34d4b103d4204904869c7e65fd486e140d8e0f4af299c6d92bdcbac6382272,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
Secret Partagé H : (3e3b4325eafe2d883511104512dc69fe6992a107a1d8491023ecd4901d3e8fb4,cab674f61a35ce386ffbf5d80878a7a354989af484c5280dff555048438f1697,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
Nouveau Point de base Gmap : (68b509b3d4e0c0ff1283e7b75248bbb9274c013a7b384e7b2567de05b3518f99,f2cb282078e1b5013328e33ce510faa7f7f390eac5873fe64a3e988846a8105d,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
Nouvel clé secrete SKPCDMap : 17651959506870056005865036021216596234247459902170306235233823787888641315788
Nouvelle clé publique éphémère  PKPCDMap du terminal : (cb1da777aceaa58d703f98de4e6948e77a5c7ef3cee210ee963fdf22413795dc,42b1bf02999a63b7464ffebd7ec44cb4aab2d1cc18db383b1b74e0aa7ced3872,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
10860000457c43834104cb1da777aceaa58d703f98de4e6948e77a5c7ef3cee210ee963fdf22413795dc42b1bf02999a63b7464ffebd7ec44cb4aab2d1cc18db383b1b74e0aa7ced387200
Send=>10860000457c43834104cb1da777aceaa58d703f98de4e6948e77a5c7ef3cee210ee963fdf22413795dc42b1bf02999a63b7464ffebd7ec44cb4aab2d1cc18db383b1b74e0aa7ced387200
Get<=7C43844104FE0236D14CBFC9F1F29C57070AA08AE4CDF6717D4724D8249B9BA5E8369821697E35BF1509527FD46BDA17E112B393DCC848C2C521F1CB2736B483ED3CEA56909000

Nouvelle clé publique éphémère  de la puce PKPICCMap : (fe0236d14cbfc9f1f29c57070aa08ae4cdf6717d4724d8249b9ba5e836982169,7e35bf1509527fd46bda17e112b393dcc848c2c521f1cb2736b483ed3cea5690,1,ffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000fffffffffffffffffffffffc)
Clé encryption Kenc : 8ce96e836836fe2162878d498cc91f26
Clé mac Kmac : 27b9ddf62e527adf8771c3f1c3de95e0
Token d'authentification : AFF6CCDC17A7752D
Send=>008600000c7c0a8508AFF6CCDC17A7752D
Get<=7C0A860812C243203402352F9000
Réponse tpicc : 7C0A860812C243203402352F9000


It might be a good idea to debug both codes and compare each of the intermediate results (or alternatively log the intermediate results for comparison). This should allow you to determine which command behaves differently in the Android code and you may be able to draw conclusions about the problem in this way. This information would also be useful, as most users will probably not be able to execute the code due to a missing environment.

What version of Core are you using.  What is your target?  I would recommend using Core 7 and make sure the target is the same.  Core 8 still has bugs.  Than make sure that the runtime version of Core 7 is install on target machine.  You need to either publish your app (which will include the runtime version of Core) or manually install the runtime version

I've edited and added the logs for both environments.

Your log only contains a tiny fraction of the values to be compared. You should compare all return values to identify the bug either from the return value itself or by comparing it with the reference code. To achieve this, the codes probably need to be adapted for troubleshooting so that both codes use the same parameters for the commands (e.g. randomly generated values should be replaced by static test values) so that the return values are comparable.

Technically, I don't have a bug, just that the value found by the algorithm is not correct, and I can't fix the SecureRandom. I thought it might be a conversion problem or a multiplication that is not done correctly. Because in the end, if the token you find does not match the token calculated by the chip, it returns the error 63CX. Here a link of the algorith : https://i.sstatic.net/6U4P2.png
